# how to get string value for the interface name outside the interface scope in PHP

Tags: php, types

I want to get interface's name into a `string`.

`get_class` function requires an object from the interface, and not the interface itself.

Theoretically, this example shows what I want to do:

```
<?php

interface MyInterface
{
/* Some code goes here */
}


$name = get_interface_name(MyInterface); # $name should hold string 'MyInterface'

?>
```

Thanks,
Ogail

Comment: so you can directly write na $name="MyInterface"; what is the issue?

Comment: You are passing an argument with the value that you want. Why don't you just assign that argument to the $name?

Comment: @Poonam: this could be a solution but I need more generic one without the need for any code maintenance if I changed the interface name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reflectionclass http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getinterfacenames.php

```
interface MyInterface
{
/* Some code goes here */
}
class Sub implements MyInterface { }

$getinterface = new ReflectionClass("Sub");

var_dump($getinterface->getInterfaceNames());
```